# How to set an attribute of a Dom element

Tags: ocaml, js-of-ocaml

I have created a td element with a call such as:

```
  let td = Dom_html.createTd doc in
```

I would now like to set an attribute on this object. I have tried this:

```
  td#setAttribute (Js.string "colspan") (Js.string "4")
```

But I get the error:

Error: This expression has type Dom_html.tableCellElement Js.t
       It has no method setAttribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple dash `#` is used to access method of OCaml object.

Js_of_ocaml has a special syntax (`##`) to deal with Javascript object.
see http://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/2.4/manual/library

To set an attribute of a dom element:

```
td##setAttribute(Js.string "key", Js.string "val")
```

In you case you should rather use :

```
td##colSpan <- 4
```

The double dash `##` will translate JavaScript field access.
The previous statement translates to `td.colSpan = 4`.

The type parameter `'a` in `'a Js.t` is a phantom type used by the type checker to check JavaScript field access. see http://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/2.4/api/Dom_html.tableCellElement-c in your case.

Comment: Note that you need to use the Js_of_ocaml syntax extension `js_of_ocaml.syntax` to use `##` syntax.